# New construction: rectangular boxes in ceiling for LED lights?

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I’m new here and looking for input on what to do with our partially finished basement re. ceiling lights.

Long story short, the original contractor bailed halfway through so I’m seeing how much I can finish myself and am moving to lighting.

Each room’s ceiling has one octagonal or round box in the center and then between 4-6 rectangular boxes around it. It appears that these are on different switches, so that each room would have two switches, one for the center box/light and one for the surrounding boxes/lights.

The rectangular boxes for the surrounding lights are confusing to me. Maybe the intent was to install low-profile LED lights that are lightweight enough to work with those rectangular boxes? Is that a thing?

I don’t want to do anything stupid here, but I sure would hate to replace all 14 rectangular boxes if I don’t need to.

What would you do?

Comment: This sounds like a very typical "4 cans and a fan" room treatment. The lighting such a setup produces is awful. Do yourself a favor and get aimable (tilt/rotate) fixtures you can bounce off the walls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are called "flush-mounted LED lights" or Junction box-mounted LED lights". None of the fixture is recessed into the ceiling so that it can mount to a rectangular junction box.

For example: [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-9-in-Color-Selectable-LED-Flush-Mount-Ceiling-Light-w-Night-Light-Optional-White-and-Brushed-Nickel-Trim-Rings-56582191/319112700).

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are led flush mount lights that attach to a standard 4inch Jbox.

( I will resist attaching a link as searching for "Jbox LED lights will give you many options.)

You can also take down the boxes and install LED puck style lights that have the cable attach in a driver box that is tucked into the ceiling.  These come in 4, 6 and 8 inch diameter sizes.  (other sizes many be out there , but I haven't seen them.)  Most all are dimmable, however if dimming is a desire, check before purchasing.

The center box may be for a fan and light. You will have to examine the box closer to see if it is rated for a fan.

Comment: Perfect. I had searched for LED lighting for rectangle boxes (not junction boxes), which surprisingly turned up very little. Thanks!